# How do viewModels fit into WebApi implementations with ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Right now I have a few layers to my project: Core <> Repository <> API... and I'll be building a "client" MVC web project layer.  My question is - where do viewModels belong in this architecture?

Should the controller methods of the Web Project call the API (multiple times - getTheseObjects, getThoseObjects) to get data, and then build the viewModel?  Or should the API support calls to construct the viewModel so that only one API call (getAllObjectsForThisPage) needs to be made per page for the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view models will belong in your client MVC app. They will be specific to the views in that individual client application, and usually will get populated by domain objects. 
This is how it can work: the controller mediates the https requests thus calls a API endpoint and receives some data or domain objects, which in turn you use to populate your view models.

Take a look at [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) if you are returning domain objects from your api, it really helps with mapping domain object to view models.

Answer (score 0):

You can place ViewModels into your MVC application, but you could create something that is called DTO (Data Transformation Object) and return that from Web API to your client. In essence it will be a class with only the necessary information that you pass to the client. If you want to call that ViewModel you might as well go ahead and call it like that. My suggestion would be to issue one call and to return all the necessary information. One call one trip.

My practice usually is to separate ViewModel from MVC and store it in some other project. The service layer would prepare a ViewModel and return it to MVC. The reason for this is that once I had a requirement to build WPF application after MVC was completed. It was quite a pain moving things around and retesting everything to make sure that it still works fine.